# The method 'map' was called on null. Tried calling: map (Closure:(dynamic) => Data)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I want to display the user's information from the API to a profile page. I am getting error that The method 'map' was called on null. Tried calling: map (Closure:(dynamic) => Data) When I tried using list builder I get internal linkedhashmap error.

below is my dart code:

```
Future<Data> fetchData() async {
final data = jsonEncode({'member_id': 0001});
http.Response res = await http.post(
  Uri.parse(
      'http://server.clientURL.json'),
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  body: data);
if (res.statusCode == 200) {
final resData = jsonDecode(res.body)['response']['profile'];
return resData.map((data) => Data.fromJson(data));
} else {
throw Exception('Unable to fetch data from API');
 }
}

class Data {
  final String position;
  final String memLname;

Data({
  required this.position,
  required this.memLname,
 });

factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return Data(
position: json['position']as String,
memLname: json['memLname']as String,
 );
 }
}

@override
Future<ProfileInfo> createState() async => ProfileInfo();

class ProfileInfo extends StatelessWidget {
late Future<Data> futureData;

ProfileInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder<Data>(
      future: fetchData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(snapshot.data!.position),
                Text(snapshot.data!.memLname),
              ],
              );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        // By default show a loading spinner.
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ),
  ),
  );
```

Comment: ```return resData.map((data) => Data.fromJson(data)).toList();```

Comment: I guess that your `jsonDecode(res.body)['response']['profile']` returns null to resData, so you get that error calling map on null value

Comment: @Mark can you share what you getting in `res.body`?

Comment: @SagarStackapp I am getting the data in the API but in the app it displays InternalLinkedHashMap error